# What files need to be distributed with zeit-pkg produced executable?

Tags: zeit-pkg

If I use pkg (https://github.com/zeit/pkg) to build an exe-file, what other files do I need to distribute with the exe?

It seems the produced .exe includes a copy of Node.js binaries. Therefore it occurred to me shouldn't I include a Node.js license-file in addition to the .exe? Or, are the copyright and license notices built into (inside) the exe enough?

Are there any other open source components that might be used BY Node.js which need attribution?

Or is it ok to distribute just the pkg-produced .exe alone? Are there any examples of such applications?